# Alternative to NetPeerTcpBinding in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf

[NetPeerTcpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) is obsolete as of .NET 4.5.
I'm wondering what viable alternatives there are for a .NET project.

Comment: I presume peer to peer functionality has been moved to the [`System.Net.PeerToPeer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.peertopeer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Apparently [using the 'faux' dns name you can also connect using NetTcpBinding](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/SlickThought/Peer-to-Peer-Series-Part-5-Connecting-Peers-via-WCF).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [Mesh.Net](http://eigenein.info/mesh-net/), it's an opensource project designed to replace the PeerToPeer binding now that MSFT no longer supports it.

Answer (score 1):

While not technically an answer, well maybe it is if we can get MS to leave it in the framework. Please go here and upvote!

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776917/netpeertcpbinding-and-other-classes-have-been-marked-obsolete-in-net-4-5-please-restore-them#details

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely troubling as I was looking into developing a solution utilizing this as well. The only viable solution I've found so far is [AllJoyn](https://www.alljoyn.org/) sponsored by Qualcomm. The problem with AllJoyn is that with the exception of WinRT applications, Windows support is limited to native C/C++ implementations, so .NET is not supported (unless you are willing to port it yourself using P/Invoke).